# Creating dataset from list of ragged associations with defaults for missing keys

Tags: dataset, associations, missing

Given the ragged dataset in form of association of associations:

```
<|
  "r1" -> <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 3          |>, 
  "r2" -> <|          "b" -> 5, "c" -> 6|>
|>
```

How do I construct a `Dataset` with missing keys set to `Missing` or default value `0`?

Like

```
<|
  "r1" -> <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 3  "c" -> 0|>, 
  "r2" -> <|"a" -> 0  "b" -> 5, "c" -> 6|>
|>
```

Of course, the actual dataset is very large and I need it in `Dataset` object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given:

```
assoc = <| "r1" -> <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 3          |>
         , "r2" -> <|          "b" -> 5, "c" -> 6|>
         |>;
```

... here is a way using `KeyUnion`:

```
AssociationThread[assoc // Keys, KeyUnion[assoc // Values, 0&]]

(* <| "r1" -> <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 3, "c" -> 0|>
    , "r2" -> <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 5, "c" -> 6|>
    |>
*)
```

The default value function `0&` can be generalized to return a different value based upon the key which is passed as an argument.  For example:

```
default["a"] := 999
default["c"] := -999

AssociationThread[assoc // Keys, KeyUnion[assoc // Values, default]]
(* <| "r1" -> <|"a" -> 2,   "b" -> 3, "c" -> -999|>
    , "r2" -> <|"a" -> 999, "b" -> 5, "c" -> 6   |>
    |>
*)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
data = <|
  "r1" -> <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 3|>,
  "r2" -> <|"b" -> 5, "c" -> 6|>
  |>
keys = Union @@ Map[Keys, data]  (* EDIT: ht Anton *)
f[a_Association] := Association[# -> Lookup[a, #, Missing[]] & /@ keys]
Dataset[f /@ data]
```

Comment: I think `keys=Union @@ Map[Keys, data]` is better. (+1)

Comment: @AntonAntonov I agree, *if* we are sure that no dataset might be missing all values for some key.

Comment: Did I not say that the dataset is very large (and I can not write all keys by hand)? Accepted with `keys=Union @@ Map[Keys, data]`

Comment: @grandrew Well no, you did not say that you do not have separate access to the keys, nor that you can be sure that a given dataset has all they keys you need.  But from your comment, you apparently intended to.  So I have edited the answer to include Anton's suggestion.